# ERROR in Entry module not found using webpack with react.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack

Someone who can help me how to solve this error when configuring the webpack.
I am using React.js

The error is as follows:

ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\react\index.js' in 'C:\react'
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! platzivideo@1.0.0 build:prod: `webpack -p --env.NODE_ENV=production`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the platzivideo@1.0.0 build:prod script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-07-22T21_33_42_548Z-debug.log

Comment: Do you have a `.` in your entry file string? I.e. not `/react/index.js`, but `./react/index.js`

Comment: Ahh I do not have that .  maybe that's it

Comment: show your webpack config, and also your folder structure.

Comment: ok not problem.